Headless Chrome / Puppeteer Disable local files
I want to be able to generate PDFs from the content of email bodies sent in by users.
Obviously I dont think that I should just trust my users to send nice emails that won't try to look at local files on my webserver. So I was wondering if it was possible to disable the file:// URL scheme somehow.
Possibly could sanitize the input before render, but I feel as though that could be possibly brittle. I would rather use a launch arg or Puppeteer feature to disable reading local files.
I guess I could spin up a separate node that is just for PDF generation but I would prefer to not do that lol
Also open to other PDF generation options, but just searching around it seems like most people suggest the headless Chromium / Puppeteer route.
Are there other security vulnerabilities to think about in regards to this?
I've basically just searched around to gather some info right now.
I would prefer to not offload this to another API as I would like to avoid the roundtrip and async errors.
